# Save Button Redirecting Unnecessarly

Tags: visualforce

I have a bunch of fields and a save function button which saves my options. The standard controller is Account and my page is a component in the Account Details Page.

```
VF
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveChange" /> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancelChange" /> 
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
Controller

public PageReference save(){

         //Assigns each objects field with values 


     return null;
    }
```

When I click the save button for my component on the Account Detail Page, it redirects me to the components VF page. It exits the account details page. Why does it do this? The VF markup is exactly as it is on my page.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your button rerender a component you shouldn't see this affect you anymore. it will do an ajax refresh on that section. IE:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" rerender="mysection"/>

<apex:outputPanel id ="mysection">
..... Display stuff
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: hey, when I add a rerender attribute and then click save, I get a "The URL no longer exists error"

Comment: Would this be a VF page embedded on your standard page layout?

Comment: It is an embedded VF page but in a custom page layout.

Comment: Yeah, those never work out correctly... i highly recommend just using an entire vf page rather than integrating it as you are attempting to do. Only time I put vf pages on custom layouts is when it's only to display information and not to edit the current record.

Comment: Hey. The only problem is I really have to embedded as it is a requirment for what I am doing. Is there anything else at all that could perhaps solve this problem?

Comment: Build a custom vf page which allows the editing of sections rather than a whole if that's the case. Problem you'll face mostly is you cannot redirect your vf page from a custom layout because of cross server scripting. So if any of your fields need to be refreshed outside of your vf page you are out of luck.